# From bivariate to trivariate probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, symmetry, exchangeability

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the space of all possible bivariate probability distributions.

Let's pick **a** bivariate probability distribution $g\in \mathcal{G}$. Can we always find a random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ such that

(1) $(X,Z)$ is distributed as $(Y,-Z)$

(2) $(Y,-Z)$ is distributed as $(-X, -Y)$

(3) $(X,Z)$ has probability distribution $g$

? As suggested in the comments below, the answer is **"NO"**, i.e., such a random vector may not exist for some $g\in \mathcal{G}$. This remark leads to my question.

**Question:**

Let $\mathcal{G}^{\diamond}\subset \mathcal{G}$ be the subset of bivariate probability distributions such that a random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ satisfying (1), (2),(3) exists **if and only if** $g\in \mathcal{G}^{\diamond}$.

Can we list the features that a $g\in \mathcal{G}$ **should** have to belong to $\mathcal{G}^{\diamond}$ (**necessary conditions**)? For example, $g$ should be symmetric wrto zero, or $g$ should belong to a certain parametric family, etc.

Is there any result of the type "$g\in \mathcal{G}^{\diamond}$ **if and only** if $g$ is [XXX]" where [XXX] is filled with some non-parametric or parametric restriction?

Comment: I suspect there may be a critical typographical error in this question, because the claim makes no reference to $(A,B)$ and only to $\mathcal G.$  There may be at least one more, too, because the claim appears to state that $C$ and $-C$ have the same distribution, which obviously is not true for all distributions, making the question rather trivial.  Could you please check your post?

Comment: You appear to be using an ambiguous notation.  Could you state exactly what you mean by the tilde operator "$\sim$"?  Usually it means "has the same distribution as," but as I pointed out before, with that interpretation your question is trivial, so I doubt that's what you intend it to mean.

Comment: @whuber I have reformulated my question. Does it make more sense now? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't cleared anything up.  Let me say in words what your notation would conventionally mean: "$(X,Z)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,-Z)$ and $(Y,-Z)$ has the same distribution as $(-X,-Y)$ and $(-X,-Y)$ has $g$ for its distribution."  Is this what you intend?  Note that for most $g,$ no such random variables exist.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the discussion. Your last point was insightful. The question has been rewritten.

Comment: Adding to @whuber comments, could you try describing the question in plain English or at least clearly describe the notation and symbols used, since different notation is used differently, so it may be confusing.

Comment: @Tim Thanks: does it look better now?

Comment: I am afraid not. Could you describe what you are trying to say in plain English? From my experience, doing so usually brings you closer to finding the solution yourself, so could be beneficial for you as well.

Comment: I think it's clear enough: you appear to be attempting to describe, in a somewhat elliptical way, bivariate distributions with marginal distributions that are symmetric about $0.$  Unfortunately, a great deal of the formulation of this question is superfluous and therefore raises doubts concerning what you're trying to ask.  For instance, there is no content at all in asserting that $(X,Y,Z)$ has a joint probability distribution: by definition, it does. The only part of the statement that appears to have any content is "$(X,Z)\sim(Y,-Z)\sim(-X,-Y).$" cc @Tim

Comment: @whuber I've reformulated the question again, deleting any reference to $f$.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now.  Would it be fair to interpret your question as asking how to determine when, given a random variable $(X,Z),$ there exists a random variable $Y$ satisfying the three conditions?  This is somewhat interesting because although obviously $X,Y,$ and $Z$ have to be identically distributed and symmetric around zero, *that is not sufficient.* For example, when the correlation of $X$ and $Z$ exists and is less than $-1/2,$ such a $Y$ cannot exist.

Comment: @whuber Yes, thanks. Indeed, $(1),(2),(3)$ implies $\{X,Y,Z\}$ identically distributed and symmetric around zero. Are there other necessary conditions on the marginal probability distributions of $X,Y,Z$ implied by (1), (2), (3)?